Paper claim a seemingly false property for weighted Voronoi cells
Section 2.1.2 of this paper makes a claim I am confused about:

The weighted Voronoi cells and their $k$-dimensional faces, 0 $≤ k ≤ d$, form a cell complex that decomposes $\mathbb{R}^d$ into convex polyhedral cells. This cell complex is called the weighted Voronoi diagram or power diagram of $\mathcal{P}$ [Aur87].

In this case "Weighted Voronoi Diagram" stands for the additive weights:
$$ Vor^\omega(p) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \|p - x\|^2 - \omega(p)^2 \leq  \|q - x\|^2 - \omega(q)^2\, \forall q \in \mathcal{P} \} $$
However, my understanding is that this sort of diagram produces cells with curved edges which are 1) not guaranteed to be convex, 2) clearly not polyhedra since their faces are not flat.
Did the paper make a wrong claim or am I misunderstanding something?

That is the definition of Laguerre-Voronoi diagram. The equi-distant locus between points is a hyperplane perpendicular (but not necessarily halfway) to the segment between the two points. That gives a decomposition as claimed.
